# Hard vibrations (sometimes)

Tags: vibration, carrier

Can someone point me in the correct direction.

Once or twice a month my air conditioner unit (the one in te basement) will make a horrible vibration that can be heard throughout the house and I mean it’s loud !!!! It will wake you up and sounds like an old tractor trying to start on a cold day

The vibration will last for an hour or so and then just stop and won’t do it again for a few weeks. The Air conditioner works fine and the heater works fine and I can find no obvious defects.

This has happened off and on for the past three years. I have had two different, professional companies, look at the unit. Both companies claim they can find nothing wrong with the unit. Both companies clean the unit and performed whatever maintenance they said needed to be done. Both companies have watched cell phone video of the vibration and knows it’s happening but still can’t find what’s causing the vibrations

The unit is a Carrier and is 7 years old. The unit was professionally installed when we built our house and we have no problems with it other than the harsh vibration that occurs once or twice a month for about an hour

We have tried replacing the filters with various makes and models. We have removed the cover while the vibrations were occurring to make sure there was not a vacuum thing happening. We have turn the unit off and back on and the vibration still occurs. We had disconnected the power overnight and when the power is turned back on the next day it will continue vibrating until it decides to stop. The technicians have checked the motors, squirrel cage, mounting brackets, and say they all are fine.

I’m well over $2,000 in service fees and really don’t want to spend anymore on it. I have emailed carrier and ask them about the above but they have not responded

I really don’t want to replace the unit and spin the $7500 for a new one

Does anyone have any idea? If need be I can send you videos of the sounds

Comment: just an idea, but are you sure it's coming from the unit?  My other son's house suddenly developed a loud noise from the vents. I went to check on it, checked the furnace, it seemed fine. I heard the noise, sounding more like a rattling. Turned out that it was a very windy day and somehow the wind got into the fresh air intake and was vibrating the ductwork! When the wind died down, the noise stopped.  That day, the wind came from a very unusual direction. Again, just a thought.  Be sure you are finding the source of the noise to fix it.

Comment: what @GeorgeAnderson said ... it could be a resonance in the ducts that happens only when the blower is on and the wind is in a specific direction .... try plugging all the vents when the noise is occuring ... also, open all the windows and doors, so that the wind does not blow through the ducts

Comment: It’s supposed to be windy and rainy tomorrow.  I’ll try anything at this point lol. 

I’ll post the results tomorrow evening.  

Thank you for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

What you are saying is not complete. You state: "my air conditioner unit (the one in the basement)" makes the noise. I would be surprised in the condenser unit is not outside.  I would guess the evaporator coils are in the furnace in the basement and you are getting something in the blower, probably ice. The fact that it goes away indicates the problem is self correcting and it takes some time for ice to melt. This would more than likely to happen when it is cooler in the evening. If I were to take a SWAG i would say the charge in not correct and the super heat is to low. That would take a professional to adjust. But first be sure all the vents are open with no restrictions. If you have in register filters remove them and replace your main filter.

Comment: That’s very interesting, I was reading an article about that same thing earlier today but that is definitely over my head.  Ill call the heating and cooling guy check Monday and run that by him

Comment: A quick test, when it happens turn the blower off for a moment then back on if it still makes noise turn it off for about 45 minutes, then if it runs ok it was probably ice. The airflow will also have a big effect, be sure no registers are blocked or closed. It is common to close lower floor registers to force AC upstairs. Let us know where you found the article.

Comment: https://www.robertbpayne.com/what-causes-an-air-conditioner-to-freeze-up/

That’s the article I was reading.  I like I said, it’s a little over my head but I’m trying to learn as I go.  So I’m very appreciative of your help.  I’ll definitely try your suggestion the next time is makes the noise.